# Property 'status' does not exist on type 'User'

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm working on a personal project with `Angular 6` as my client and `Laravel 5.6` as my API and I can't understand what going on with my auth service.

For some context: I would like to implement `jwtAuth` to manage my user authentification and it is working perfectly (I've tested the api endpoints with Postman). Now, this is my register function:

```
public function register(RegisterFormRequest $request)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->username = $request->username;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => '¡Usuario registrado!',
            'user' => $user
        ], 200);
    }
```

As you can see, this function returns a json with an status, message and the user information. On the client side, this is my `auth.service.ts` "register user" function:

```
registerUser(user: User):Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.url}/register`, user, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError((e:Response) => throwError(e))
      );
  }
```

Whichs returns the exact same json that i've define on my API if everything goes fine. Finally, in my `register.component.ts`, this is the function that i use to implement that service function:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.authService.registerUser(this.user).subscribe(
      response => {
        swal({
          type: response.status,
          text: response.message,
          footer: 'Usted será redirigido hacia el formulario de ingreso.',
          showConfirmButton: false,
          showCloseButton: false,
          showCancelButton: false,
          allowEscapeKey: false,
          allowOutsideClick: false,
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

Just like that, it does not work because it throws the next error:

```
Property 'status' does not exist on type 'User'.
```

By the way, here is my `user` class:

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  password_confirmation: string;
}
```

And I assume that it will do just the same with the `response.message` and I think it is related to the `Observable` handler but i can't understand how it works. If i remove those to lines of code, everything works so... How can I solve this problem?

PD: Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: try to console.log(reponse) and see what return

Comment: It shows me the json that i am returning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add status to your user type:

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  password_confirmation: string;
  status: string;
}
```

otherwise you can just return Observable from your service.

```
registerUser(user: User):Observable<Any> {
    return this.http.post<Any>(`${this.url}/register`, user, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError((e:Response) => throwError(e))
    );
}
```

Comment: So, it's totally fine to use the Observable<Any> just like that ?

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdez yes

Answer (score 1):

It's because your function `registerUser` is returning an observable of type `User` :

```
registerUser(user: User):Observable<User>
```

and when you call it :

```
registerUser(this.user).subscribe(
  response => {
    swal({
      type: response.status,
```

`response` is supposed to be of type `User` (because you has specified it), so change your return type to Angular http response or any and then response will be able to have the status property :)

Comment: It is not necessary to use the Observable at all ?

Comment: You need Observable type to get the subscribe completion and check but you can use HttpReponse from angular `Observable<HttpResponse>` or `Observable<Any>` to bypass type check

Answer (score 1):

You are casting your response to a user, when its actually the response type you created on your api:

```
}
  status: string
  message: string
  user: User
}
```

So, if you dont care about the status fields or message fields, just map the response to just return the user.

```
//Create a response type or interface or class
export interface RegisterUserResponse {
  status: string
  message: string
  user: User
}



registerUser(user: User):Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.url}/register`, user, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError((e:Response) => throwError(e)),
        map((resp: RegisterUserResponse) => {
          return resp.user; //this should satisfy 'this.http.post<User>'
        })
      );
}
```

Comment: I actually care about the message and status, i would to display them on my swal function!